# What town is meant by the location Gorn. Laknic?

Tags: 19th-century, vital-records, austria, austria-hungary, slovenia

I have a transcription provided by the Ljubljana church archives of Slovenia that says that Jozefa Zaman was born at Gorn. Laknic 8 on 17 Aug 1843.  You can see an example of this underlined in red in this the Status Animarium (S.A.) from the Šentrupert parish:
[image]

According to the Ljubljana translator, from Slovenian, this means "Upper Laknice" in English, but I don't locate any such town in my Google searches.

Here is another S.A. record from Šentrupert:
[image]

And here is an S.A. from the Ljubljana archives for book to 1873 to 1885:
[image]

And one last S.A. from Ljubljana for book 1886 to 1897:
[image]

Here is an extra S.A. from what appears to be the brother of Jozefa that shows the same town of birth:
[image]

What is the proper name of the town and where exactly is it located?  What is its parish (e.g., Šentrupert) and what diocese (e.g., Ljubljana).

Comment: Could the images be cropped more so you aren't posting the entire register page? Since most of your entries are near the top of the page, I suggest keeping the headers but cropping the bottoms of the pages where the Kraj is blank.

Comment: @JanMurphy I've cropped all the images down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place is probably [Gorenje Lakovnice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorenje_Lakovnice), Novo Mesto, Slovenia, "and belongs to the Parish of Novo Mesto–Šmihel".

As in a [previous answer](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/13750/what-does-location-boshte-mean/13757?s=1%7C25.3157#13757), Fuzzy Gazetteer and GOV led to the above result.

In the record images, "Gorn." is clearly an abbreviation; the full word seems to have a number of grammatical forms, depending on the following word.

Comment: Do you think Gorenje Lakovnice means same thing as Upper Laknice per the archivist's direction at the diocese?  What does `Gorenje` translate to in English?

Comment: I don't speak Slovenian - but the initial letters "gor"  are Slovenian for "up"