# What does location Boshte mean?

Tags: 19th-century, palaeography, vital-records, german-language, kurrent

I've got a Status Animarium from Ljubljana in the early 1800s written in German using Kurrent handwriting and it lists a birth location as ditto Boshte, underlined in red, but I don't understand what that is exactly:

[image]

In later records, loco is used to mean the same location as the current household.  In this case, the household is Mali Cirnik 13, so does Boshte mean the same location in German?  Google translate says it is not a word.  Is this some kind of old style German spelling?  What is the exact word in German and what does it mean for the location of birth?

Here is the whole page in case more context is needed:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The place may be [Boršt, Slovenia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bor%C5%A1t,_Koper). (See [Boste](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boste) for an alternate spelling of the name that is closer to the spelling used by the church record).

When a placename is (probably) mis-spelled, try

- [Fuzzy Gazetteer](http://dma.jrc.it/fuzzyg/query/) or
- [GOV](http://gov.genealogy.net/search/index) or
- [JewishGen Gazetteer](https://www.jewishgen.org/Communities/LocTown.asp), etc.,

followed by other resources, to evaluate which results make the most sense.

Notes: 
* Boshte is not a German word. 
* GoogleTranslate often doesn't do well with placenames. 
* Probably irrelevant, but interesting given the mining connection mentioned in other posts, GoogleTranslate, using Detect-Language setting, returns "shafts" as the translation of an Albanian word "boshte" (but this doesn't explain the "do" preceeding the word on the above record)

Comment: But the dto. would suggest same as above right?  Above is Klien= Zirnik.

Comment: The do. [=ditto] SHOULD be referring to the previous entry in the same column, however having a second word (Boshte) complicates that. Either the ditto is referencing something else above, or we've mis-interpreted the abbreviation or possiby (who knows!) Boshte is a street name or neighbourhood identifier (is Klein-Zirnik big enough to need sub-divisions?)

Comment: Klein Zirnik (present day Mali Cirnik) is tiny and always has been, no need for subdivisions.  Veliki Cirnik is about a mile away to the west.

Comment: The ink looks the same but some of the letters in Boshte don't look like the same as elsewhere on the page -- that word could have been added by someone else, possibly later. In that case, the ditto was the original entry and the 2nd word has another purpose.

Comment: Boshte means empty in Albanian.